# obj\Debug\90\MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs specified more than once in the "Sources" parameter

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I get this error when compiling an android xamarin project. I have checked my csproj and there are no duplicates. Any help?

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask].

Comment: Try check your csproj file, maybe it is duplicated in there somehow.

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO ! Does this exists after crearing new xamarin android project ? If no , you can remove `bin` folder to rebuild it to check . If yes , you need to check whether install the full needed develop package for [Android SDK 9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows#platforms-tab)